# Oracle Clob data type and java.sql.ResultSet.getString() working?

Tags: oracle, jdbctemplate, clob

we need to update varchar2(4000) type to Clob to accommodate large data. Here data are being saved and retrieved using **java.sql.ResultSet.getString()** of JdbcTemplate with Oracle 19c.

If we have just updated data type from varchar2 to clob, it is working fine with existing code where we have used getString().

We are unable to find rationale why this is working or any enhancement at Oracle to have transformation seamlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultSet.getString()` works with multiple database data types, including `VARCHAR2` and `CLOB`.